# Insert line above while clearing indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

While using VS Code, quite often I want to add 2 lines above my current position. Ideally, I'd like to use `⇧⌘Enter` twice, but when I do that I get an empty line with indentation:

```
····*cursor is now here*
····*blank line with indentation*
····some code *cursor was here* some code
```

I would like the same behavior that the command insert line below `⌘Enter` has, which removes the indentation of the empty line automatically:

```
····some code *cursor was here* some code
*blank line without indentation*
····*cursor is now here*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new command that replaces the key binding and have the requested result.

Use the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) and add this to your `settings.json`

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.lineAbove",
      "sequence": [
        "cursorHome",
        "cursorHome",
        "cursorUp",
        "cursorEnd",
        "cursorEnd",
        { "command": "type", "args": { "text": "\n" }}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The command repetitions are to handle long lines and word wrap.

Add the following to your `keybindings.json`

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+enter",
    "command": "-editor.action.insertLineBefore"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+enter",
    "command": "multiCommand.lineAbove"
  }
```

You have to change the key combos for your Mac OS.